# Why Power BI connector Fails to save modifications to the server?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am consuming from Active Directory connector; and, I start to get the data, but at around the row 20,000 I get this error:

[image]

I am pretty much following this guide:
https://matt40k.uk/2016/06/getting-a-list-of-ad-groups-and-their-members-using-powerquery/

PowerQuery:

[image]

I remove Nulls before consuming too:

[image]

Consuming only 2 columns:
[image]

Any idea how can I prevent it from failing?